# Trying to get progress from copyfileobj in Python

Tags: python, copy

```
from threading import Thread

src_file = 'test.txt'
dst_file = 'test_copy.txt'

def cb(file_size):
    print("Copied: {}\n".format(file_size))

def copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst, callback, length=8*1024):
    copied = 0
    while True:
        buff = fsrc.read(length)
        if not buff:
            break
        fdst.write(buff)
        copied += len(buff)
        callback(copied)

t = Thread(target=copyfileobj, args=[src_file, dst_file, cb]).start()
```

When I run this I get:

> buf = fsrc.read(length) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute
>   'read'

How should I make that `fsrc` has read attribute?

Comment: you need to `open(fsrc) as f` to get a handle.`read` works on a file handle, not a filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're mixing up file *name* and file *handle*.

You have to `open` the files using the filename to get the file handle, for both reading & writing.

```
def copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst, callback, length=8*1024):
    copied = 0
    with open(fsrc,"rb") as fr, open(fdst,"wb") as fw:
      while True:
        buff = fr.read(length)
        if not buff:
            break
        fw.write(buff)
        copied += len(buff)
        callback(copied)
```